# Function return value of x instead of y

Tags: python, function

f(x) represents the function of a triangular waveform. In which you input the value x and it returns you the associated y value. However my function returns x every time instead of y. For example f(1) should give 2/pi instead of 1.

```
def f(x):

    y=x

    if x in arange(-math.pi,-math.pi/2):
        y=(-2/math.pi)*x-2


    elif x in arange(-math.pi/2,math.pi/2):
        y=(2/math.pi)*x


    elif x in arange(math.pi/2,math.pi):
        y=(-2/math.pi)*x+2

    return y
```

Comment: Unless you had exactly 1 in the array then you match nothing, print each arange and it will be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) returns an array of non-consecutive numbers. `in` operation against it will return `True` only if the left-hand operand belong to those numbers.

You'd better to use `<=` / `<` pair to avoid such problem. In addition to be correct, it also save cost of creating arrays.

```
def f(x):
    y = x

    if -math.pi <= x < -math.pi/2:
        y = (-2/math.pi)*x-2
    elif -math.pi/2 <= x < math.pi/2:
        y = (2/math.pi)*x
    elif math.pi/2 <= x < math.pi:
        y = (-2/math.pi)*x+2

    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'in' keyword only checks if the searched element lies in the list. Here, your list contains only values in the step of 1. Perhaps the value of x is not an integral step. Hence, the corrected function would be:

```
def f(x):

    y=x

    if x>-math.pi and x<-math.pi/2:
        y=(-2/math.pi)*x-2


    elif x>-math.pi/2 and x<math.pi/2:
        y=(2/math.pi)*x


    elif x>math.pi/2 and x<math.pi:
        y=(-2/math.pi)*x+2

    return y
```